# VBA - object required error while generating PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a Pivot table in vba.

I am almost sucessfull in creating it. below is my code,

```
Sub Pivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As pivottable

Set ws = Sheets("Cat_Pivot")

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Preparation Sheet!R1C7:R1048576C8")

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.range("B3"))    
With pt    
    With .PivotFields("Category")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With .PivotFields("Colour")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

   .AddDataField.PivotFields ("Colour"), "count of colour", xlCount     
End With

End Sub
```

I get an object required error, when I add the line

> .AddDataField.PivotFields ("Colour"), "count of colour", xlCount

Before adding this line I am able to create a Pivottable. How can i rectify this ?

I went through the available resources,as  far i know, I have declared the variables by dim Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space between `.AddDataField` and `PivotFields ("Colour"), "count of colour", xlCount` inside the `With pt` statement.

change your:

```
.AddDataField.PivotFields ("Colour"), "count of colour", xlCount
```

to:

```
.AddDataField .PivotFields("Colour"), "Count of Colour", xlCount
```

without the `With` statement it's:

```
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Colour"), "Count of Colour", xlCount
```

Comment: Issue rectified. I should add the Statement before with. Now it works fine. :) sorry for the wrong comment update.

Comment: just one more comment... why all my column lables are not seen  ? i could only seen green and red.. Yellow is missing . how can i overcome _

Comment: Problems resolved :) thank you for the Support :) thanks a ton